# Bootstrap Div tag Presentation

Tags: html, css

Im trying to replicate this [Boostrap tile effect](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/bootstrap-3-tips-and-tricks-you-might-not-know),which presents the pages content,I assumed that they were  tags but cant find a suitable way of styling,are there any tutorials you can point me to that can replicate this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you should do is inspect the element via your browser to get an idea of how they are creating the style. You can learn a lot by looking at other people's code.

The site has a structure like this:

```
<div class="tile">
    <div class="tile-content">
       content here
    </div>
</div>
```

The style is applied to the **tile** class.

The css would look like this:

```
.tile{
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 400px;
 }
```

I created a fiddle so you can see it in action and play with it.

http://jsfiddle.net/pfca6rnu/

Good luck!